# Comando de artisan que genera el CRUD + rutas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, artisan

hace un par de años que no utilizó Laravel, sino php puro, pero este mes me tocó usarlo porque un cliente me ha solicitado un desarrollo en ese Framework, yo recuerdo que todo el MVC lo creaba con un comando de artisan, el cual me creaba las vistas, los modelos, los request, los controladores, migraciones e incluso las rutas con solo ejecutar 1 linea y al final el nombre de la pagina, por ejemplo: php artisan create NOMBREPAGINA y ya con eso tenia todo el crud, solo era modificar las vistas y controladores.

Estuve buscando en internet y me apareció el comando php artisan crud:generate NOMBREPAGINA  pero este no es el que yo usaba, y además da error al ejecutarlo.

Que comandos de `php artisan` puedo utilizar??

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: La versión 8 de Laravel no incluye comando alguno para generar un crud (y no tengo referencia de que alguna versión lo haya tenido) como tal, tienes por ejemplo la opción de crear: model, factory, seeder y migración del modo siguiente: `php artisan make:model Model --all`. Probablemente lograbas eso que mencionas por tener algún paquete extra instalado, puedes buscar alguno y usarlo

Comment: No hiciste ninguna pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar las opciones adicionales que ofrece laravel:

Por ejemplo puedes comenzar creando el modelo, con el controlador configurado como recurso con los 7 verbos http y la migracion:

```
php artisan make:model -mcr
```

Aqui te va mas opciones, que muestra la terminal:

```
-a, --all             Generate a migration, seeder, factory, and resource controller for the model

-c, --controller      Create a new controller for the model
-f, --factory         Create a new factory for the model
--force           Create the class even if the model already exists
-m, --migration       Create a new migration file for the model
-s, --seed            Create a new seeder file for the model
-p, --pivot           Indicates if the generated model should be a custom intermediate table model
-r, --resource        Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller
--api             Indicates if the generated controller should be an API controller
-h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
```